# Why is the left-multiplication map a surjection in this context?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, linear-transformations, modules, proof-explanation

I will be awarding a bounty for this question as soon as I can, because this is a problem that is bothering me for quite a while now.

Here is a theorem that I know is true.

> Let $S$ be a simple ring and $L$ be a non-zero left ideal of $S$.
>   Consider $D:= \operatorname{End}({ }_S L)$. Note that $D$ acts on $L$
>   via evaluation. Then the natural map
>
> $$f: S \to \operatorname{End}_D(L_D): r \mapsto (f_r: L \to L= l
>  \mapsto rl)$$
>
> is a ring isomorphism.

and I want to prove the following:

> Let $R$ be a $k$-algebra where $k$ is an algebraically closed field.
>   Suppose that $V:= k^n$ is a simple left $R$-module. Then the map
>
> $$f: R \to \operatorname{End}(V_k): r \mapsto (f_r : V \to V: v
>  \mapsto r.v)$$
>
> is a surjection.

In my notes, a short proof is sketched. I will post it here:

> Consider the ringhomomorphism $f: R \to \operatorname{End}(V_k): r
>  \mapsto f_r$. This induces a well-defined ring monomorphism
>
> $$\overline{R}:=R/\ker f \hookrightarrow \operatorname{End}(V_k):
>  \overline{r} \mapsto f_r$$
>
> Note that $\overline{R}$ is finite-dimensional as $k$-algebra, because
>   $\overline{R}$ embeds in $\operatorname{End}(V_k) \cong M_n(k)$. Thus
>   $\overline{R}$ is Artinian, and hence the quotient ring
>   $\overline{\overline{R}}:=\overline{R}/J(\overline{R})$ ($J$ is the
>   jacobson radical) is Artinian as well. Thus $\overline{\overline{R}}$
>   is a semisimple ring.
>
> By Wedderburn-Artin, there are simple rings $B_1, \dots, B_m$ such
>   that $$\overline{\overline{R}} \cong B_1 \times \dots \times B_m$$
>
> Now, note that $V$ is a simple left $\overline{R}$ -module for the
>   action induced by the action of $R$ on $V$. Since $V$ is simple, we
>   have $J(\overline{R})V = 0$ and hence we can view $V$ as a simple
>   $\overline{\overline{R}}$-module, essentially with an equivalent
>   module structure as the one induced by the $R$-action on $V$.
>
> Going further, we can view $V$ as a simple $B_1 \times \dots \times
> B_m$-module, and we get
>
> $$V= (B_1 \times \dots \times B_m) V = B_1 V \oplus \dots \oplus B_m
> V$$
>
> where we have identified $B_i$ with natural ideal of $B_1 \times \dots
>  \times  B_m$. Since $V$ is simple, there is a unique $i \in \{1,
>  \dots, m\}$ such that
>
> $$B_i V \ne 0; \quad V = B_i V$$
>
> Employing the theorem above, we get an isomorphism
>
> $$h:B_i \to \operatorname{End}(V_k): b \mapsto h_{b}$$
>
> Composing with the obvious surjections
>
> $$R \to \overline{R} \to \overline{\overline{R}} \to B_1 \times \dots
> \times B_m \to B_i \to \operatorname{End}(V_k)$$
>
> the result follows. $\quad \square$

**Question:**

> How exactly is the theorem above applied to get that  $$h:B_i \to
>  \operatorname{End}(V_k): b \mapsto h_{b}$$ is an isomorphism (and thus
>   a surjection)?
>
> I.e. what ideal $L$ is used? It seems that more is going on because I
>   really can't understand this step.

For anyone trying to help, thousand times thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right: a bit more is going on here. Let's denote $B:=B_i$ for the sake of brevity.

As $V$ is simple, we can choose a nonzero element $v_1\in V$ such that $B\cdot v_1 = V$ and then extend it to a $k$-basis $v_1,\dots,v_n$ of $V$. Then we can consider the chain of left ideals
$$
L_m:= \{b\in B\mid b\cdot v_j =0,\quad j=2,\dots,m\},\quad m\leqslant n.
$$
Obviously, $L_1=B$. If now for some $m\leqslant n$ we have $L_m\neq 0$, but $L_{m+1}=0$, we get that $b\cdot v_{m+1} \neq 0$ for all $b\in L_m$, and so the map $\mu\colon L_m\to V$, $b\mapsto b\cdot v_{m+1}$ is

- injective, because if $b\in L_m$ and $b\cdot v_{m+1}=0$, then $b\in L_{m+1}=0$;
- surjective, because $L_{m}\cdot v_{m+1}$ is a non-zero $B$-submodule of $V$, and the latter is simple;
- a map of $B$-modules by construction.

Thus, $\mu$ an isomorphism of $B$-modules, and we can apply the theorem to $L=L_m$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! I need some time to digest this answer. In the meantime, can you add to this answer how this isomorphism of modules brings us closer to seeing we have this surjection?

Comment: Well, we just realised our $V$ as an ideal $L$ of a simple ring $B$ “in disguise”. Now, $D=\mathrm{End}(_BL)\cong \mathrm{End}(_BV)$ is just $k$, because if we have a nontrivial (=non-scalar) endomorphism $T$ of $V=k^n$ commuting with $B$, we get a non-trivial submodule (just take an eigenspace of $T$) and this is forbidden by simplicity of $V$. So, the theorem tells that $B$ is isomorphic to $\mathrm{End}(L_k)\cong\mathrm{End}(V_k)$.

Comment: But in the end we want to end up with the left multiplication map and there are some identifications going on here. Don't we need to compose them explicitely and see that we get the right map?

Comment: Sure, that's why I insisted that $\mu$ is an isomorphism of $B$-modules (viewing $L_m$ as a $B$-module by left multiplication).

Comment: Alright. Let me take some time to digest this. Thanks again and merry christmas!